# Duplicate `Content-Type` headers in Postman

Tags: request, http-headers, postman

If you ever duplicate a header Postman overrides the preceding header and tells you `This is a duplicate header and will be overridden by the <header-name> header added by you.` A few days ago I imported a collection with an MTOM SOAP request that duplicates the `Content-Type` header as depicted below and I'm not sure how this was achieved because I can't find documentation on the subject. I'd like to achieve the same ability.

[image]

Comment: it happens automatically whats the question now ?

Comment: content type is added automatically if you add a separate one then that will be seelcted

Comment: @PDHide The question is I'd like to duplicate the `content-type` header as opposed to the default ability of overriding one.

Comment: > content type is added automatically if you add a separate one then that will be seelcted What

What if I want to keep both as illustrated in the picture above?

Comment: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/5372

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postman changes the automatically add headers if you add an explicit one, if you want to have two content type then manually add two headers. Both headers will be send

[image]